# How to work with one List on few Classes without effects on that list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I'm comparing a few algorithms.Each algorithms(class) received the same list. The problem is that first class affect on list and other classes cannot work on that list. 
Is there any clever way to do this?

Here is a code:

```
Lista = []
start = 54
for i in range(25):
   liczba = random.randint(1,179)
   if liczba not in Lista and liczba != start:
      Lista.append(liczba)
   else:
      i -= 1

print "Lista: ", Lista


x = SSTF(Lista)
x.Symulacja(91)  #<----- OK!

y = FCFS(Lista)
y.Symulacja(25) #<----- FCFS received epty list.

z = SCAN()
z.Symulacja(start, Lista)

w = C_SCAN()
w.Symulacja(start, Lista)


results = Result()
results.Add(x) 
results.Add(y) 

print Results
```

SSTF is removing elements from list which received, FCFS the same. So after doing SSTF algorithm FCFS reveived empty list. I can't understand why this list is affected. I'm not working on List "Lista", but  in **init** of SSTF i'm assigning "Lista" to other list.

Sorry if my problem is not a clear. I'm learning python and that problem hits me many times.

Comment: If you own the callables (classes I believe) make them pure. If not, use immutables, replace your lists with tuples?

Comment: I do not own callables (as I said i've just learn python ;)). Tuple couldn't work it that case. I do too much operations on list. The strange thing for me is that assigning in python means reference. So List = List2 = [1,2,3] means that some operation on List2 do the same on List. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: call the function with a copy: `x = SSTF(Lista[:])`.

Comment: Yay, that solve my problem. Thank you Daniel. :) But still for me, python fail in that case. I do not remember that kind of problem in others languages.

Comment: Many languages will have just that same kind of problem on reference-type variables :-).  You have to _really_ understand this concept if you want to know programming.

Comment: This is horrible code, you're changing i within the loop, this is buggy in python (cpython) as the implementation keeps an internal reference to the i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = SSTF(Lista[:])
y = FCFS(Lista[:])
....
```

etc...

Your problem:

```
def SSTF(Lista):
    Listb = Lista
```

means that Listb is still the same Lista, because this is a reference to the same object.

To avoid it, copy the list entirely, using [:] slice notation (Python dictionaries have the .copy() method, which is clearer).

Basically, any time you copy a reference to an object from one variable to another variable, you are ending up with two pointers to the same object so changes to that object will be seen by both variable names.  Yeah, sorry about the terminology.

The pointer is shown by the id() code below.  Notice how li == li2 != li3

```
>>>li = [1,2]
>>>li2 = li
>>>li3 = li[:]
>>>li2.append(3)
>>>print "li:", id(li), li
>>>print "li2:", id(li2), li2
>>>print "li3:", id(li3), li3

li: 4385880760 [1, 2, 3]
li2: 4385880760 [1, 2, 3]
li3: 4385924376 [1, 2]
```

This is not the case with things like numbers or strings.  Check out also the concept of 'immutable'.

```
  >>> a = "xxx"
  >>> b = a
  >>> b = b +"y"
  >>> print a, b
  xxx xxxy

  >>> a = 1
  >>> b = a
  >>> b =b+1
  >>> print a, b
  1 2
```

If you need to copy your custom classes' instances, look into the copy module, but keep in mind that instance attributes are either shared or copied, depending on using copy.copy(x) or copy.deepcopy(x).  In practice, this is rarely necessary, but I got bitten many times by Lista type issues on built-in collection classes before I learned my lesson.